# Перемещение математического маятника

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

есть код математического маятника который реагирует на перемещение мышью, как сделать так чтобы он реагировал на прикосновения тач скрина в мобильной версии?

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
    * {  margin: -100; }
    canvas {display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
</style>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" style="background: #eee"></canvas>
</body>
<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var h = canvas.height = 450;
var w = canvas.width = 600;
var h2 = canvas2.height = 100;
var w2 = canvas2.width = 200;
 
var draggin = false; // В режиме перемещения  
var dragX = 0; // Центр канваса, относительно которого будем считать поворот
var dragY = 0;
var dragPhi = 0; // Угол маятника при нажатии
var dragKsy = 0; // Начальный угол при mousedown
 
ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
ctx2.translate(0, h2 / 2);
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0, 0);
 
var initPhi = Math.PI * 0.2;
var L = 200;
var dt = 1 / 60;
var g = 1500;
var t = 0;
 
bob = {
  phi: initPhi,
  v: 0,
  a: 0
};
 
//getPos - определение позиции относительно центра элемента
function getPos(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: rect.left + rect.width / 2.0,
    y: rect.top + rect.height / 2.0
  };
}
 
// Определяем угол поворота относительно центра канваса
function calcKsy(evt) {
  var deltaX = evt.clientX - dragX;
  var deltaY = evt.clientY - dragY;
  var Ksy = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
  return Ksy;
}
 
// Обрабатываем событие нажатия на левую кнопку мыши
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
  var gpc = getPos(canvas);
  dragX = gpc.x;
  dragY = gpc.y;
  draggin = true;
  dragPhi = bob.phi;
  dragKsy = calcKsy(evt);
});
 
// Поворачиваем маятник на угол между начальным углом при mousedown
// и текущим после перемещения курсора
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
  if(draggin){
     var Ksy = calcKsy(evt);
     bob.phi = dragPhi - Ksy + dragKsy;
  }
});
 
// Обрабатываем событие отжатия левой кнопки мыши
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
  draggin = false;
  bob.v = 0;
  bob.a = 0;
});
 
function drawPendulum() {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(Math.sin(bob.phi) * L, Math.cos(bob.phi) * L, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
  ctx.lineTo(Math.sin(bob.phi) * L, Math.cos(bob.phi) * L)
  ctx.stroke()
}
 
function update() {
  bob.a = -(g / L) * Math.sin(bob.phi)
  bob.v += bob.a * dt
  bob.phi += bob.v * dt
  t += dt
}
 
function drawGraph() {
  ctx2.lineTo(t * 20, (bob.phi % Math.PI) * 20)
  ctx2.stroke()
}
 
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h)
  drawPendulum()
  // Если мы не в режиме перетаскивания, то качаем маятник
  if (draggin === false) {
    update()
  }
  drawGraph()
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
 
draw()
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: для этого есть события c превфиксом `touch` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events думаю по аналогии можно будет угадать названия но на всякий случай `down` это `start`  а `up` это `end`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Переделал ваш код так, чтобы он работал и на телефонах. Я использовал touch события для реализации задуманного, подробнее о них смотрите тут: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var canvas2 = document.getElementById("canvas2");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var ctx2 = canvas2.getContext("2d");
var h = canvas.height = 450;
var w = canvas.width = 600;
var h2 = canvas2.height = 100;
var w2 = canvas2.width = 200;
 
var draggin = false; // В режиме перемещения  
var dragX = 0; // Центр канваса, относительно которого будем считать поворот
var dragY = 0;
var dragPhi = 0; // Угол маятника при нажатии
var dragKsy = 0; // Начальный угол при mousedown
 
ctx.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
ctx2.translate(0, h2 / 2);
ctx2.beginPath();
ctx2.moveTo(0, 0);
 
var initPhi = Math.PI * 0.2;
var L = 200;
var dt = 1 / 60;
var g = 1500;
var t = 0;
 
bob = {
  phi: initPhi,
  v: 0,
  a: 0
};
 
//getPos - определение позиции относительно центра элемента
function getPos(el) {
  var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();
  return {
    x: rect.left + rect.width / 2.0,
    y: rect.top + rect.height / 2.0
  };
}
 
// Определяем угол поворота относительно центра канваса
function calcKsy(evt) {
  var deltaX = evt.clientX - dragX;
  var deltaY = evt.clientY - dragY;
  var Ksy = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
  return Ksy;
}
 
// Обрабатываем событие нажатия на левую кнопку мыши
canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function(evt) {
  var gpc = getPos(canvas);
  dragX = gpc.x;
  dragY = gpc.y;
  draggin = true;
  dragPhi = bob.phi;
  dragKsy = calcKsy(evt);
});
 
// Поворачиваем маятник на угол между начальным углом при mousedown
// и текущим после перемещения курсора
canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(evt) {
  if(draggin){
     var Ksy = calcKsy(evt);
     bob.phi = dragPhi - Ksy + dragKsy;
  }
});
 
// Обрабатываем событие отжатия левой кнопки мыши
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(evt) {
  draggin = false;
  bob.v = 0;
  bob.a = 0;
});
 
//////////// Часть позволяющая коду работать на телефоне 
canvas.addEventListener("touchstart", function(event) { //Аналог mousedown
    var gpc = getPos(canvas);
    dragX = gpc.x;
    dragY = gpc.y;
    draggin = true;
    dragPhi = bob.phi;
    dragKsy = calcKsyPhone(event);
    
}, false);

canvas.addEventListener("touchmove", function(event) { //Аналог mousemove
    if(draggin){
     var Ksy = calcKsyPhone(event);
     bob.phi = dragPhi - Ksy + dragKsy;
    }
    event.preventDefault();
}, false, {
    passive: false
});
canvas.addEventListener("touchend", function(event) { //Аналог mouseup
    draggin = false;
    bob.v = 0;
    bob.a = 0;
   
    event.preventDefault();
}, false);

function calcKsyPhone(evt) { // Переделал вашу функцию под touch события 
  var deltaX = evt.touches[0].clientX - dragX;
  var deltaY = evt.touches[0].clientY - dragY;
  var Ksy = Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX);
  return Ksy;
}
/////////////
function drawPendulum() {
  ctx.beginPath()
  ctx.arc(Math.sin(bob.phi) * L, Math.cos(bob.phi) * L, 10, 0, 2 * Math.PI)
  ctx.fill()
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0)
  ctx.lineTo(Math.sin(bob.phi) * L, Math.cos(bob.phi) * L)
  ctx.stroke()
}
 
function update() {
  bob.a = -(g / L) * Math.sin(bob.phi)
  bob.v += bob.a * dt
  bob.phi += bob.v * dt
  t += dt
}
 
function drawGraph() {
  ctx2.lineTo(t * 20, (bob.phi % Math.PI) * 20)
  ctx2.stroke()
}
 
function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(-w / 2, -h / 2, w, h)
  drawPendulum()
  // Если мы не в режиме перетаскивания, то качаем маятник
  if (draggin === false) {
    update()
  }
  drawGraph()
  requestAnimationFrame(draw)
}
 
draw()
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<style>
    * {  margin: -100; }
    canvas {display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
</style>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<canvas id="canvas2" style="background: #eee"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```